# How can I stop my Instagram from playing videos fast when I upload?

Tags: playback, instagram

Recently I've run into a problem on Instagram where when I upload videos the playback is slightly off. It plays a little too quickly which annoys me. Can someone help me with this?

I usually post videos in 30fps

Comment: Sorry to sound unhelpful, but you won’t get any useful answers to this without a lot more information - starting with which version of Ubuntu, hardware, any recent changes to your system that might have changed settings, etc. Anyone trying to help you here hasn’t got much to go on!

Comment: At the very least, provide a technical description of the problem that is not ambiguous. It's unlikely that anyone will have any idea what you are describing.  Give us the exact steps you are taking to reproduce the problem from start to finish in a way that is clear enough that it is reproducible on our end.